# Why can't I connect to the Hana database through Python but can through Hana Studio?

Tags: python, hana, hdbcli

I have the following setup in Hana Studio and the connection works:

[image]

[image]

As you can see I selected "Multiple containers" and "Tenant database".

My python code is:

```
from hdbcli import dbapi

conn1 = dbapi.connect(
    address='the same as hdb studio', 
    port=30015, 
    user='User', 
    password='*****',
    databasename='HCE'
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: (-10709, "Connection failed (RTE:[89006] System call 'connect' failed, rc=10061:No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it {0.0.0.0:55875 -> 192.160.50.98:30015} (0.0.0.0:55875 -> 192.160.50.98:30015))")
```

Any ideas, it could by because the Tenant database?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you checked that it's actually running on port 30015? Have you tried running with the IP instead of the hostname? Are you running from the exact same machine as the Hana Studio is running on, or from some other machine (even a VM)? From the documentation: "For HANA system databases in a multitenant system, the port number is 3NN**13**." https://pypi.org/project/hdbcli/ - most likely cause is the wrong port number.

Comment: @Grismar Thank you for your answer.
Yes in Hana Studio it's running in that port, even I only put the instance 00 and automatically Hana Studio gives me the port.
Yes I already tried with the IP instead of the hostname.
Yes I'm in the same machine, I had to put a line in hosts file in windows system 32 folder.

IDK what else to do.

Comment: Have you even tried 30013?

Comment: @Grismar yes, I got a different error:

Error: (10, 'authentication failed')

But the credentials are correct.

Comment: Authentication failed means you're at least reaching the server - and although you feel the credentials are correct, the server is telling you it disagrees. The error in your question just means there's no service there - nobody is answering the phone. Perhaps you need to look at how the user or password needs to be passed. For example, if the user is a Windows user, perhaps the domain needs to be specified. Or perhaps you're having case-sensitivity issues, etc.  Look at the logging, perhaps it tells you more about why the authentication failed.